# Local Wordpress err_empty_reponse when editing pages/posts

Tags: php, wordpress, git, .htaccess, openshift

Hi I am using [Openshift](https://openshift.redhat.com) to deploy a [Wordpress](http://www.wordpress.com) website. I already have a running wordpress installation. I copied files and the exported db. Now I used https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-wordpress-developer-quickstart.git cartridge to deploy a new wordpress clone because I want to makes changes first locally then push them with git.

After that **locally** I changed `siteurl` and `home` values in `wp-options` table to 'http://localhost:8888'. Then I created an `.htaccess` file with the following contents:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The admin panel and the website are working ok. The only problem is that when I edit a post or try to make a new post from admin panel it fails with the following error:

```
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I went to the MAMP logs and in `apache_error.log` I see only this error each time I try to create a new post:

```
[Thu Jul 20 12:38:19 2017] [notice] child pid 10443 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

In the php_error.log I do not see anything relevant other than this:

```
[20-Jul-2017 10:20:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/andi/sites/website/wp-includes/class-wp.php:633) in /Users/andi/sites/website/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1121
```

Strange behaviour is that when I deploy this files and the same database to openshift all these problems are not present. I cannot figure why?!

**EDIT**
Locally I have php v7.0.x while on the openshift server php v5.4. Maybe is a php version issue?

**EDIT 2**
Changed local php version to 5.4 and same error appears :(

**EDIT 3**
Disabled and deleted all plugins, switched to a standard theme, no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the [Wordpress cartridge](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-wordpress-developer-quickstart.git) had Wordpress version 3.9. Updated Wordpress to the latest version (4.8) and everything worked also locally.